# How can I replace empty dictionary entries with the last entry

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

I have a text file. The left side shows the current landuse and the right side the historical landuse. It is separated by a pipe character (`|`). It Looks like this:

```
landuse 1    |landuse x
landuse 2    |\n
landuse 3    |\n
-----------------------
landuse 4    |landuse y
-----------------------
landuse 5    |landuse z
landuse 6    |\n
```

now I have to create a dictionary like this: `'landuse 1': 'landuse x', 'landuse 2': 'landuse x'` and so on. So I have to replace the `\n` with the last used value landuse x, y or z.

```
      Textfile=open(r"G:\....txt","r")
      d={}
      for line in Textfile:
          x=line.split("|")
          a=x[0]
          b=x[1]
          c=b.strip("\n")
          e=a.strip()
          f=e.strip("-")
          g=c.strip("-")
          d[f]=g
      print(d)
```

I already created this script, but for landuse 2,3 and 6 I  get an empty equivalent. How can I fit landuse x / landuse z in that space?

Comment: Is there a literal `\n` in your file? Or it's just to show there is a newline? In case of former, I can update the answer. :)

Comment: You *really* need to use better variable names. Meaningful variable names will make you code much easier for others (including future you) to understand and maintain. That said, `pandas` `ffill` might be a solution for you.

Comment: no it is not literal in the file, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
for line in Textfile:
    try:
        (key, value) = line.split("|")
    except ValueError:  # split() did not result in two items.
        continue        # This will deal among other with the delimiter lines ----
    key = key.strip()
    value = value.strip()
    if value:  # string is not empty after stripping
        d[key] = value
        prev_value = value  # save for next line if needed
    else:
        d[key] = prev_value  # assign last seen value as there isn't any new one
```

Please note, this example is very rudimentary and still leaves open some cases open. For instance it would fail with `NameError` if first entry had no value in second column (you could set it before entering the loop, but what would the correct value be, perhaps failure is a correct action in that case). You may actually want to (example input would suggest so) reset the `prev_value` when hitting the delimiter? We did not actually perform any checks on the input beyond `|` splits it into two parts.

As written your script should have actually raised `IndexError` on `b=x[1]` when processing the delimiter (`----`) as that should have yielded single item list.

Also when using `\` in file names, make sure you use raw string literals `r"g:\somefile.txt"` to avoid surprises (or just use forward slashes, Windows in the meanwhile knows what to do with those, few unruly applications may not still).

---

Replace `if value:` with `if value != '\n':` in case your input actually has literal '\n` string instead of just blanks followed by newline for lines where previous value should be used.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish this, you need* a variable outside of the scope of the for loop, so that it can retain the information from previous loops. Here we add a variable `previous_landuse` which will be updated with the latest occurrence of the right side landuse. When a line does not have a right side, it will use this variable to fill in the blank, as that was the last value for that column.

```
Textfile=open(r"G:\....txt","r")
d={}
previous_landuse = ''
for line in Textfile:
    x=line.split("|")

    #ignore the -------- line
    if len(x) < 2:
        continue

    key = x[0].strip()
    value = x[1].strip()

    if value == '':
        value = previous_landuse
    else:
        previous_landuse = value

    d[key] = value

print(d)
```

Output:
`{'landuse 1': 'landuse x', 'landuse 2': 'landuse x', 'landuse 3': 'landuse x', 'landuse 4': 'landuse y', 'landuse 5': 'landuse z', 'landuse 6': 'landuse z'}`

*you don't technically need it outside of the scope, but it is good practice to do it like this, as some languages are much stricter with for loop scopes.

Comment: Thank you so much it runs!! :-)

Comment: @Leonie No problem, happy to help! Make sure to mark it as answered pls :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems straightforward if you use conditions. Something like this:

```
for line in Textfile:
    x = line.split("|")
    a = x[0]
    b = x[1]
    if r"\n" not in b:
        tmp = b
    c = tmp.strip("\n")
    e = a.strip()
    f = e.strip("-")
    g = c.strip("-")
    d[f] = g
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using pandas. I am going to assume that your text file contains this exactly

```
landuse 1    |landuse x
landuse 2    |\n
landuse 3    |\n
-----------------------
landuse 4    |landuse y
-----------------------
landuse 5    |landuse z
landuse 6    |\n
```

including the `\n` and the `-----`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv',
                 header=None,
                 sep='|')
df.columns = ['id','value']

# Get rid of the `-------`
df = df.dropna()

# Replace the literal '\n' with missing values
df.loc[:,'value'] = df.loc[:,'value'].replace({r'\n':None})

# Now just forward fill
df = df.ffill()
```

the final contents of `df` is:

```
              id      value
0  landuse 1      landuse x
1  landuse 2      landuse x
2  landuse 3      landuse x
4  landuse 4      landuse y
6  landuse 5      landuse z
7  landuse 6      landuse z
```